# How to let users of MyClass, control which version of the class is instantiated by means of a compiler flag?

Tags: c++, c++11, compile-time

I have a C++ class that runs in time-sensitive code, such that merely constructing the object may take more time than users can spend.  I'd like to define both a standard and a trivially-constructible version of my class, and let users of the class control which version of the class is instantiated by means of a compiler flag.  I'd like the compiler flag to work at the level of a `group`.  For example, if the flag were `LEVEL=:OFF,GROUP1:ON`, then the trivial version would be constructed for all instances of the class except those in `GROUP1`, which would get the actual, non-trivial instantiation.  The goal is for users to be able to turn off certain groups at compile time, by changing the flag value.

I'd like to use C++11's `std::conditional` to control which version of the class is used.  To do this, I need to check the group with which a given usage of the class is associated, and compare it to the compiler flag setting for that group.  I can't think of a way for users of the class to pass a compile-time setting to the main class definition from the user's source file.  I could require users to put something like `#define MYCLASS_GROUP ON` in their source file, but I don't think I can reference that in the file where my class is defined.

Is there a way for users of a class to control the compiled version of a class from the user's source file?  Thanks in advance for any ideas here!

Update: Here is how I'd ideally like this to be used.  A user could do:

```
#define MYCLASS_GROUP GROUP1

MyClass myClassInstance;
```

Then, they could control which version is instantiated via a compiler flag.  So `-DMYCLASS_GROUP_LEVEL=:OFF,GROUP1:ON` would enable use cases like the above, in `GROUP1`.

In the class definition, I'd like something like the following non-working pseudo-code:

```
class MyClassOn {
  non-trivial code here
};
class MyClassOff {
};
typedef std::conditional<check-group-here, MyClassOn, MyClassOff>::type MyClass;
```

Comment: Why not wrap your class with a template - possibly using CRTP - where a non-type template parameter is provided by the user (the instantiator) and the template chooses (via specialization) the proper constructor?  (Doesn't actually require `std::conditional` ... hope you aren't really counting on that ...)

Comment: Pass the define(s) as a compilation option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use template specialization.

First declare the options:

```
class DefaultVersion;
class TriviallyConstructible;
```

Next create the primary template definition of the class

```
template <typename T = DefaultVersion>
class MyClass;
```

Specialization for DefaultVersion:

```
template< >
class MyClass< DefaultVersion >
{
    // ...
};
```

Specialization forTrivially-Constructible version

```
template<>
class MyClass< TriviallyConstructible >
{
    // ...
};
```

Example of usage

```
MyClass<> m1;
MyClass< DefaultVersion > m2; // same as m1
MyClass< TriviallyConstructible > m3;
```

And if the users wants they can declare an alias for this type, which can be used in there application.

---

### How to pass compile time flag to class?

Through preprocessor directives and aliasing.

```
#ifdef GROUP1 > 0
using MyClassGroup1 = MyClass< TriviallyConstructible >;
#else
using MyClassGroup1 = MyClass< DefaultVersion >;
#endif
```

Or another way:

```
#ifdef GROUP1 > 0
using Group1 = TriviallyConstructible;
#else
using Group1 = DefaultVersion;
#endif
```

and at place of usage

```
MyClass< Group1 > m4;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Robert- this sounds like it will work for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MYCLASS_GROUP GROUP1
MyClass myClassInstance;
```

doesn't work. Usually if you need to tweak lib code by preprocessor you define identifier before including lib header.

```
#define MYCLASS_GROUP GROUP1
#include <MyClass.h>

MyClass myClassInstance;
```

In `MyClass.h` you just check what is defined.

In your particular case you don't need preprocessor, as nicely described in Robert Andrzejuk answer.